# Webview in Electron does not allow to share screen?

Tags: javascript, webview, electron, webrtc, electron-forge

I am trying to create an Electron app which runs webview of Google meet.
Everything works fine but when I try to share screen it show error "browser does not support share screen".

Is there any possible way to share screen in webview in Electron?

This is my main.js file

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow, desktopCapturer } = require('electron')
    
let mainWindow
    
function createWindow() {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            webviewTag: true
        }
    })

    mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')

    mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
        mainWindow = null
    })

    mainWindow.webContents.on('did-finish-load', function() {
      
    })
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit()
    }
})

app.on('activate', function () {
    if (mainWindow === null) {
        createWindow()
    }
})
```

This is my html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <webview
          autosize="on"
          src="https://meet.google.com/"
          id="webview"
          data-home="https://meet.google.com/"
          style="width: 100%; height: 100vh;"
        ></webview>
    </body>
</html>
```

Some people suggest to use the desktopCapturer module of Electron but how can I use it in webview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use desktopCapturer to share the screen in the load URL
add this code in **app.whenReady().** this will automatically screen the first available screen

```
session.defaultSession.setDisplayMediaRequestHandler((request, callback) => {
    desktopCapturer.getSources({types: ['screen']}).then((sources) => {
        callback({video: sources[0]});
     });
 });
```

but if you want to select a particular screen you need to implement your own desktop picker dialog [desktopCapturer](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/desktop-capturer) in Electron.
for that instead of passing sources[0] in callback emit an electron event which show all the available screen and then return your particular source id and pass it to `callback({video: sources[id]});`

it may be not work in the case of google meet screen sharing because Google(security) does not allow this but it works in my case when I have to load [bigbluebutton video conferencing](https://bigbluebutton.org/) web app in electron through load URL